What does an average homeowner do for pipe cement when only a small amount is needed?
I have to make maybe 5 total connections between PVC pipes, adding a backup sump pump. I don't expect to have any other plumbing tasks for a year, fingers crossed. Last time I bought PVC pipe primer and cement, I used a tiny bit of it (less than a quarter of the can), then stored it sealed and in a cool dark basement drawer. I went to use it again many months later (maybe over a year later) and found it had 'gone bad' by thickening and clumping up. I'd prefer to avoid that waste. What is a DIYer to do when only a tiny amount of pipe glue is needed? I hoped to avoid a plumber for this simple job, but maybe the tradeoff is they economies of scale for supplies like this.
Is there a reason not to use other glues I have around the house, like gorilla glue that can connect to plastic?
Bonus if an answer gives me an option without PFAS. Very few pipe cements are PFAS-free, here is one example but is not at local hardware stores that I've seen. I realize I may just need to use whatever conventional pipe cement there is, and that's fine, but I'd rather not waste 90% of the can I buy.

You'll incur much more waste by using products that don't properly weld the pipe components. Use the right product and move on. They make small cans for a reason.

Well, that's why I ask. But the small cans don't seem that small to me, I end up using less than 25% of it.

consider changing your title from pipe compound to pipe cement

See also Can I thin thick PVC cement with primer?

I'd ask neighbors if they have leftovers, it's a common problem. Other than that, you buy the smallest can you can find, use what's needed, then mark the first opening date on the can using a sharpie. 6 months later, put the can outside, open it so that the volatiles escape, then dispose with household waste. I would not use one past 6 months or so, although if it was closed hard enough to need a wrench to open then perhaps it may have not dried out much.

Why close the question? This isn't asking for a product recommendation that becomes obsolete. I'm asking how to minimize use of a standard/necessary type of product that comes with significant environmental harm (PFAS). It's a question of methods or options homeowners have in accomplishing a basic plumbing task.

It's a good question because I ask myself the same thing whenever I buy a pack of the stuff just to make one repair, and face the same problem as you.
I think the best option is to just buy the two-part glue and use what you need.  But some other options are:

I don't think code requires you to use two-part cement for a sump pump, so you could waste little less buy buying a small container of one-part glue.  But you don't save much money, and it's a pumped system so you should guide yourself by code anyway, and if you buy the two-part you can use it if needed for something drain related.

You can use rubber no-hub couplers for everything if you think that's environmentally better. And you should use at least one so you can easily maintain/replace the pump.

You can ask friends, or a local neighborhood Facebook or similar group if you can borrow some.  That can be quite effective.  The lender may even want to come help.  Build a network of local DIY-ers and you can support one another this way.



The corollary to your "crazy expensive" for Fernco-type fittings for sump pump drain piping is that in an emergency where a sump pump has failed and needs to be replaced as quickly as possible, Ferncos make the job really easy because they are quick to loosen/tighten, and don't involve needing to cut/glue PVC pipe or worry about dried out PVC solvent.

Are those rubber fittings sufficient to join pipes that will have water pumped through them, hold up with check valves in place, etc.? If so, for the reason @MIlwrdfan noted, I'd much prefer that route. I already have 2 extras sitting around from some piping I had to replace last year - added bonus that they seem to be reusable.

And great point about DIY network. Checking with neighbors and some local friends was my plan A at this point. The rubber fittings would be easier to service in an emergency though, I didn't realize those might be sufficient.

I have Fernco-style couplers on both my main and backup sump pumps, and have had no leaking at all, and I have them on both sides of check valves for both pumps.  The most they're holding back is about a 5' head of water, so it's not high pressure at all compared to a water supply.

Thinking through it more, those rubber connectors seem to only work for certain applications. I need to fit pipe into a Y-fitting, a 90-degree bend, maybe a 45-degree bend. In that case the PVC pipe has a female and a male end, while the rubber Fernco fittings look like they'd only work for male-to-make connections. So I'm back where I started, needing to somehow glue male-to-female connections so they're secure.

Fernco rates their standard rubber couplings for "maximum test pressure 4.3 PSI." That's about 9 feet of head. Ordinary operating pressure should be less than that though we don't know by how much. They seem really to be oriented toward gravity drain/waste/vent use. IMHO it's a little sketchy to use them for pumped drainage.

Ferncos routinely survive pressure tests on DWV systems, and are almost always the second or third fitting in a sump pump system, connecting the pump to the rest of the glued up pipes.   Leaking is not a problem.

@Milwrdfan Good points, I removed the cost reference from the Answer,  and noted that at least one coupling should be removeable.

@cr0 ya you probably shouldn't use rubber couplings for everything.  Why do you need a Y?   Sump pumps should not share outflow pipes, and especially not if you have a water-powered secondary pump.

I recommend "no-hub coupler" and "shielded no-hub coupler" rather than "Fernco". The latter's one of those unintuitive and regional terms that isn't helpful to the uninitiated.

@jay613 thanks it makes sense to me to just use one of those, to more easily swap out the pump from the rest of the pipes. The Y is to join the backup sump to the primary sump. The installer piped the primary pump out through the sump side and up through concrete they poured. Rather than go through lid and lay a whole 2nd discharge run, I figured I'd Y join them together in the sump if it's deep enough as I est. it will be. I'd have a check valve on each pump before the Y joins their discharge. I figure only one pump should be discharging at any time, so why lay two discharge lines?

What, exactly is a "no-hub coupler"? Is that anything like a fernco?

What kind of back up pump do you have?  How does it work?

@jay613 this is the DC battery backup pump I plan to plumb into the primary pump's discharge line https://www.homedepot.com/p/Wayne-ESP25-Upgraded-12-Volt-Battery-Back-Up-System-ESP25N/306897416#overlay We're on a well and don't have whole house generator, and rather than get an inverter for main sump pump, it seems like a DC secondary pump is the best bet

I can't vouch for the average homeowner, but what I did was buy a can of PVC adhesive, then put the remainder on the shelf with other maintenance materials in case I wanted to do something with PVC in the reasonably near future. Note the PVC can be useful for things other than plumbing.

It does address it. "It's cheap." Worrying about waste is honorable, but in this case not worth doing in my opinion

The question was "what does the average homeowner do". I bet dollars to donuts that this is exactly what they do; buy it, use it, shelve it, forget it. Of course that's an obsolete bet, since these days donuts often cost more than a buck, but still. (I officially detest Autodefect. Apologies for tupograpihk errrors.)

You convinced me.
